# How to prevent Ubuntu from switching default audio output device to Analog Output when docked?

Tags: sound, 19.04, thinkpad, docking

I have 19.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad T580. When my laptop is not docked, default audio output device is "Speakers - built-in". But when I put my laptop in a docking station, it changes default audio output device to "Analog Output - ThinkPad Dock USB Audio".

I don't have any speakers connected to my dock, so I would like to continue to have audio out of the built-in speakers. Of course, I can just change it back manually every time I dock my computer, but it would be much nicer, if it just stopped changing default audio output device whenever I docked my computer.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: This should do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185903/why-cant-i-set-a-default-output-audio-device-in-ubuntu-19-10/1186131#1186131

Answer (score 16):

I found a solution to this.

1. Open this file in an editor
   `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
2. Find and comment out the line containing this
   `load-module module-switch-on-connect`
3. Then, restart pulseaudio with
   `pulseaudio -k`

This solution was modified from 
https://danielgibbs.co.uk/2019/06/prevent-automatic-change-of-audio-device-ubuntu/

Comment: works on 20.04.2 also

Comment: Yeah, well, that's not really a solution, because now it doesn't change audio device automatically EVER - not when I plug in my headphones, not when I plug in an HDMI cable. These should still be active, it's just the *docking* event that shouldn't change audio device. How do I do that?